# SSH port forwarding

Tags: server, ssh, remote

I have a remote server, an SSH connection, and the remote server has the ip 0.0.0.1 (for example). On the server I have an application on 80 port. When I want to connect to the remote server I use:
`ssh -L 8888:127.0.0.1:80 -i path/to/key login@0.0.0.1`
after I can open the remote app from my localhost: `127.0.0.1:8888`

But in the protected network there is a site `www.example.com`, And I can access to it only from the server. The command `curl www.example.com`  is ok, but how to open the site from my remote machine? I tried `ssh -L 8888:www.example.com:80 -i path/to/key login@0.0.0.1`  logged in but how to open it? [www.example.com:8888](http://www.example.com:8888) ? 127.0.0.1:8888 ? Neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is expecting the host header. I tried it and it works for me.

```
In one terminal
▶ ssh -L 2345:google.com:443 root@k1

In another terminal
▶ curl -kIL --header "Host: google.com" https://localhost:2345/
HTTP/2 301 
location: https://www.google.com/
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Thu, 05 May 2022 12:31:08 GMT
expires: Sat, 04 Jun 2022 12:31:08 GMT
cache-control: public, max-age=2592000
server: gws
content-length: 220
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine `www.example.com` has the ip address 1.1.1.1. This command has solved my problem:

`sudo ssh -L 80:1.1.1.1:80 -L 443:1.1.1.1:443 -i path/to/key login@0.0.0.1`

also in `/etc/hosts` have to add `127.0.0.1 example.com`

Then it is possible to connect to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) directly from the browser.